# How to waitForElementVisible in Silk Performer?

Tags: performance-testing, silk-performer

What is the Silk Performer 16.5 (Web Browser driven) equivalent of Seleniunm IDE's waitForElementVisible? I cannot find it in the help or manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if found out the function below basicaly does the same as waitForElementPresent in selenium IDE and did work for me in the Silk Performer Script.

BrowserFind(HANDLE_DESKTOP, "//INPUT[@id='send']", true, 60000, false);